# How to allow layouts unless on specific pages?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I got this problem :

I have some pages linked to my application.html.erb file that are rendered my "layouts/_header.html.erb" and "layouts/footer.html.erb". 
These pages are forms that I use as popover so I don't want them to show header and footer again :

[image]

I'm looking for a way to allow header and footer unless on specific pages, something that works on each pages of my app
 (application.html.erb)  :

```
<% if controller_name == 'pages' && action_name == 'main' %>
#show nothing...
<% else %>
<% render 'layouts/header' %>
<% end %>
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put this on the controller that you don't want to use the layout:

```
YourController < ApplicationController
  layout false
```

If you only want to remove the layout from some views use:

```
def view
    ...
    render :layout => false
end
```

or:

```
layout false, :only => :edit
```

Comment: I’m going to add it to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

We shouldn't have a hard code like this, to render any view without layout template we can use this in controller

```
render 'index', layout: false
```

index.html.erb is my view here